# Plotting a single point with ListPlot gives strange outcome

Tags: plotting

I have the following simple coordinate, which I am trying to plot:

```
xy = {0, 0.963738}
```

I am trying:

```
ListPlot[xy, Joined -> False, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0.5, 1}}, PlotStyle ->{Thick}, PlotLabels -> Placed[{"Isolated"}, {Scaled[1], After}]]
```

Why is the outcome (note x=2 and not 0 as I expected):

[image]

Comment: `ListPlot` always expects a list of points, not just a point. `xy = {{0, 0.963738}}` would be a single point: a list of points containing only one element, which is itself a list of two coordinates. If you want to add a single point to another plot, you may also consider the [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) option.

Comment: If you call ListPlot with a single list of values MMA plotsthe listindex  as x-value!

Answer (score 3):

```
xy = {{0, 0.963738}};
P = ListPlot[xy, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0.5, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Or use [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point /@ xy}]
```

[image]